# How to solve these problems of compiling QT 5.15 using QT 5.15 source code on windows 10?

Tags: qt, cmake

I got the source code for QT 5.15 from this site：
https://invent.kde.org/qt/qt/qt5/-/tree/kde/5.15?ref_type=heads

```
git clone git@invent.kde.org:qt/qt/qt5.git
```

Then I execute this command in a cmd window

```
E:\Source Code  for QT5\qt5>init-repository.bat
```

Then I install these tools:

Perl 5.36, Python 3.7.3, Ruby 3.0.6 , MinGW-builds gcc 8.1, Visual Studio Community 2019 , git 2.44, mariadb-connector-c-3.1.5-win64.msi, CMake 3.28.3

Then I Follow this link: conf.q5_15wx6v9 from https://github.com/Fsu0413/Fs-scripts/blob/master/Compile/lib/qtCompile/conf.lua for the configure parameter

I open the tool : x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019

Execute the following command：

```
C:\SourceCodeforQT5\qt5-build>..\\qt5\configure -cmake-generator "Ninja Multi-Config"  -debug-and-release -opensource -shared  -confirm-license -platform win32-msvc -pch -nomake examples -nomake tests -qt-doubleconversion -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -no-icu -opengl dynamic -ssl -schannel -sql-sqlite -sql-odbc -sql-mysql "MYSQL_INCDIR=C:\\Program Files\\MariaDB\\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\\include" "MYSQL_LIBDIR=C:\\Program Files\\MariaDB\\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\\lib" -make tools -webengine-proprietary-codecs
```

The error is reported as follows:

```
-- Windows 10 SDK version: 10.0.19041.0
Overriding option 'doubleconversion' with 'qt' (was: 'undefined')
'C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe' '-DQT_INTERNAL_CALLED_FROM_CONFIGURE:BOOL=TRUE' '-DBUILD_WITH_PCH=ON' '-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON' '-DQT_QMAKE_TARGET_MKSPEC=win32-msvc' '-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=cl' '-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=cl' '-DQT_BUILD_EXAMPLES=FALSE' '-DQT_BUILD_TESTS=FALSE' '-DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES=Release;Debug' '-DINPUT_doubleconversion=qt' '-DINPUT_system_zlib=no' '-DINPUT_pcre=qt' '-DFEATURE_icu=OFF' '-DINPUT_opengl=dynamic' '-DFEATURE_ssl=ON' '-DFEATURE_schannel=ON' '-DINPUT_sql_sqlite=yes' '-DINPUT_sql_odbc=yes' '-DINPUT_sql_mysql=yes' '-DFEATURE_webengine_proprietary_codecs=ON' '-G' 'Ninja Multi-Config' '-DMYSQL_INCDIR=C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\include' '-DMYSQL_LIBDIR=C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\lib' 'C:/SourceCodeforQT5/qt5'
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30154.0
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30154.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C++ compiler
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"
  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: 'C:/SourceCodeforQT5/qt5-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-nulqm3'

    Run Build Command(s): C:/PROGRA~1/CMake/bin/ninja.exe -v -f build-Release.ninja cmTC_a8efc
    [1/2] C:\PROGRA~2\MIB055~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1429~1.301\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo /TP -DCMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\"  -MD /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\cmTC_a8efc.dir\Release\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj /FdCMakeFiles\cmTC_a8efc.dir\Release\ /FS -c C:\SourceCodeforQT5\qt5-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-nulqm3\testCXXCompiler.cxx
    [2/2] C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_a8efc.dir\Release --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100190~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100190~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_a8efc.dir\Release\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj  /out:Release\cmTC_a8efc.exe /implib:Release\cmTC_a8efc.lib /pdb:Release\cmTC_a8efc.pdb /version:0.0 /INCREMENTAL:NO /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
    FAILED: Release/cmTC_a8efc.exe
    C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_a8efc.dir\Release --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100190~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100190~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_a8efc.dir\Release\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj  /out:Release\cmTC_a8efc.exe /implib:Release\cmTC_a8efc.lib /pdb:Release\cmTC_a8efc.pdb /version:0.0 /INCREMENTAL:NO /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
    LINK: command "C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_a8efc.dir\Release\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj /out:Release\cmTC_a8efc.exe /implib:Release\cmTC_a8efc.lib /pdb:Release\cmTC_a8efc.pdb /version:0.0 /INCREMENTAL:NO /su-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
bsystem:console kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=1" failed (exit code 1) with the following output:
    C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: cannot find /nologo: No such file or directory
    C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: cannot find /out:Release\cmTC_a8efc.exe: Invalid argument
    C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: cannot find /implib:Release\cmTC_a8efc.lib: Invalid argument
    C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: cannot find /pdb:Release\cmTC_a8efc.pdb: Invalid argument
    C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: cannot find /version:0.0: No such file or directory
    C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: cannot find /INCREMENTAL:NO: No such file or directory
    C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: cannot find /subsystem:console: No such file or directory
    C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: cannot find kernel32.lib: No such file or directory
    C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: cannot find user32.lib: No such file or directory
    C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: cannot find gdi32.lib: No such file or directory
    C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: cannot find winspool.lib: No such file or directory
    C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: cannot find shell32.lib: No such file or directory
    C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: cannot find ole32.lib: No such file or directory
    C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: cannot find oleaut32.lib: No such file or directory
    C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: cannot find uuid.lib: No such file or directory
    C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: cannot find comdlg32.lib: No such file or directory
    C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: cannot find advapi32.lib: No such file or directory
    C:\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: cannot find /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=1: No such file or directory
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (project)


CMake Error at C:/SourceCodeforQT5/qt5/qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:1091 (message):
  CMake exited with code 1.


CMake Error at C:/SourceCodeforQT5/qt5/cmake/QtIRProcessHelpers.cmake:153 (message):
  C:\SourceCodeforQT5\qt5/qtbase/configure.bat -top-level -cmake-generator
  Ninja Multi-Config -debug-and-release -opensource -shared -confirm-license
  -platform win32-msvc -pch -nomake examples -nomake tests
  -qt-doubleconversion -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -no-icu -opengl dynamic -ssl
  -schannel -sql-sqlite -sql-odbc -sql-mysql MYSQL_INCDIR=C:\\Program
  Files\\MariaDB\\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\\include
  MYSQL_LIBDIR=C:\\Program Files\\MariaDB\\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\\lib
  -make tools -webengine-proprietary-codecs exited with status: 1

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/SourceCodeforQT5/qt5/cmake/QtTopLevelHelpers.cmake:35 (qt_ir_execute_process_and_log_and_handle_error)
  C:/SourceCodeforQT5/qt5/cmake/QtTopLevelHelpers.cmake:57 (qt_tl_run_toplevel_configure)
  C:/SourceCodeforQT5/qt5/cmake/QtTopLevelConfigureScript.cmake:17 (qt_tl_run_main_script)
```

How to resolve the above error ?

Comment: Remove the MinGW stuff from your PATH env var when compiling with MSVC